# How to alter the background of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

I'm struggling to modify the background-color of an iframe.
This iframe aims to load an external page (external domain).
Indeed, I tested the basic way to apply `style="background-color:#fff"` upon it, but it isn't applied:

`<IFRAME allowtransparency="true" style="background-color: #FFF" src="http://pagetoload.htm" width="250" height="420"  scrolling="no" frameborder="1"></IFRAME>`

Is there a good way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
});
</script>
```

this solution makes use of jquery. Don't forget to add jquery library.
You can do it with this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll test it, and i'll let you know

Comment: please thumb up if works!

Comment: You should mention that your solution makes use of jQuery, even if it seems obvious for some people.

Comment: @AlexanderNicholasPopa Here's my work, and it seems that your solution doesn't work...  [MyExamplePage](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXrXIKx31sK5CyXYGNWZ?p=preview)

Comment: have you added the jquery libary?  your example page is also blank for me

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> add this in your head section.

Comment: @SamDenton the black page you see, is my loaded page.I've deleted all my index.html content to make the code more readable...

Comment: @AlexanderNicholasPopa same thing....it doesnt work

Comment: @gamliel I guess he said 'blank', not 'black' :)